# How to read values in a text document and then make then parse them to ints in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, object

I'm trying to read lines of a text document and take the average of the numbers. My plan was to first read ALL the data in the text file. Then split the string up into a String array, then parse each index into an `int` array. This is my code up to the point of reading the document.

My Text Doc:

3, 7, 24, 66,

10, 50, 20, 40,

100, 20, 69, 911,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Testing 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try 
        {
            String path;
            path = "TestNumbers.txt";
            File f = new File(path);
            FileReader re = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(re);
            String line = "";
            String store = "";
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                store = store + line;
            }
            System.out.println(store);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output: 3, 7, 24, 66, 10, 50, 20, 40,100, 20, 69, 911,

In a perfect world I want the values to be separated by either "," or " ".

I tried modifying the `store = store + line + " ";` but this failed because it would iterate the space even when `readLine()` was on a blank line.

I can traverse the arrays to parse the `int` and take the average, but setting up this string to be split is stumping me. I tried `String.replace()`, `String.trim()`, and another one that failed me. This isn't homework, I'm in highschool AP CS and this is my own independent study.

**Thanks everyone for the help, you all showed plenty of ways to do it. Ended up going with .replace, and made the " " into "". Then just split via the commas. I do want to try out that regex thing though. Thanks everyone again.**

Comment: Look into Sting.split(). It has what you're looking for.

Comment: @user3473949 OP already mention about that

Comment: `if (line.length () > 0) {store = store + line;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scary Wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417069/how-to-read-values-in-a-text-document-and-then-make-then-parse-them-to-ints-in-j#comment41481297_26417069) how to handle blank lines.

You could do a .replace to swap all " " chars for "," chars. If you expect both like ", " in some cases you could even .replace those into just "," first. These are basically tricks.

You could look at String.split(regex) since the regex could be a pattern like "[, ]+" to take any number of spaces and/or commas between numbers as a separator.

Here's a quick demo I tested (skipping the file input, since you seem to have that figured out):

```
public class tmp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "1,2, 3, 4\n5, 6, 7\n\n,8"; //what we would read from file
        input = input.replace("\n"," "); //simulate removing newlines, ignore this
        String[] items = input.split("[, ]+"); //regex split
        for(String one : items) {
            System.out.println(one);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other two solutions *may* be already what you need, however here is a more idiomatic approach which handles edge cases *properly*:

```
{
    String path = "TestNumbers.txt";
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            builder.append(line);
        String[] split = builder.toString().split("\\D+");
        int[] numbers = new int[split.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++ )
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
        // 'numbers' now stores every digit segment there is in your string.
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Notable:

- Declare `BufferedReader` as `Closeable` in a try-with-resources scope.
- Do not concatenate `String`s in a loop, use `StringBuilder` instead.
- Split  to `\D+` to remove all non-digits, obtaining digit segments as elements in the final array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Testing 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try 
        {
            //open a file
            String path;
            path = "TestNumbers.txt";
            File f = new File(path);
            FileReader re = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(re);

            String line = ""; //reads a line
            String store = ""; //combines all the lines

            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) //for each line
            {
                if(line.length() > 0){ //only add to store if the line contains something
                    store = store + line + " ";
                }
            }

            //create the string array
            String[] finalString = store.split(", ");
            //and the integer array to hold the numbers
            int [] intArray = new int [finalString.length];
            //parse the string array and put each index to the integer array
            for (int i = 0; i < finalString.length; i++){
                intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(finalString[i]);
            }

            //simply calculating the average
            //summing up
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
                sum = sum + intArray[i];
            }
            //printing the average
            System.out.println("Average: " +  sum / intArray.length);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```